# How do I retrieve information from the document of the current logged in user of my app?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

While registering/signing up a user, I store data in 3 fields in each users document: Name, email and username.
I have a button, pressing which reveals a welcome message as such: "Hellow, (username)", but this fails to read the username of the current user, ie the user that is currently logged in, and instead displays the username of any other random user.

I can read the email of the current user by using Firebase Auth, ie:

```
Auth.auth().currentUser?.email
```

but I cannot read the username of the current user, which I understand is not saved in the Authentication side of Firebase.

Here is the code I've already tried:

```
func loadUserData() {
guard let email = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email else { return }
emailString = "\(email)"



self.db.collection("users").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
    if let err = error {
        print("Error: \(err)")
    } else {
        for document in snapshot!.documents {
            let emailRetrieved = document.get("email") as! String
            let usernameRetrieved = document.get("username") as! String

            print("ATTEN: 658")
            self.emailString = emailRetrieved
            print(self.emailString)
            self.usernameString = usernameRetrieved
            print(self.usernameString)

        }
    }
  }
}
```

which is exactly what the documentation suggests. The code above just prints out the email and the username of *all the documents under the collection "users."*

The name of my document is "users", and each user's information is saved in their individual document which is names as their user ID, if that helps. I'd really be grateful if someone could help, I've been stuck on this issue for a while now.

Comment: What else do you want to print out if you have access to the email and username? Somehow I don’t understand the problem.

Comment: I have a button, pressing which reveals a welcome message: "Hello, \(username)!"      However, this tends to display a different user's username sometimes, which creates an obvious problem. I want to be able to fetch the username of simply the current logged in user!                                                                 (Thanks for replying, I'll edit the question to make it clear)

Comment: Ok but you wrote “but it just prints out the requested fields...”. Do you get a list of all documents?

Comment: I edited the question; but yes, under "ATTEN: 658", it prints the email and the username of *all* the individual user documents, which I do not want. Instead, I want it to simply print the username of the user that is currently logged into the app.

Comment: Problem is, that you are iterating through all your users in your db. Try to get just one document from your db. Also firestore counts all your document reads. So try to keep your reads as minimal as you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to create a field with the uid of your users from firebase auth in your document or the document-id itself. In this [repo](https://github.com/JoeBeer/tandemPartner/blob/master/functions/usersEndpoint.js) under `usersEndpoint.js` take a look ath the `exports.createUser`.

```
...
usersCollection.doc(userRecord.uid).set({
                uid: userRecord.uid,
                firstname: user.firstname,
                lastname: user.lastname,                
                dateOfBirth: user.dateOfBirth,
                sex: user.sex,
                city: user.city,
                activities: user.activities,
                offers: user.offers
            })
...
```

With this approach you can change your code like this:

```
func loadUserData() {
...
let uid= Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

self.db.collection("users").get(uid) { (snapshot, error) in
    if let err = error {
        print("Error: \(err)")
    } else {
        ...
    }
  }
}
```

That way it should be much easier for you to get the right document of your users.

Sorry, that my code is not in swift. It's been a while that I coded in swift. But I hope that helps.

**EDIT**

Alternatively you could do is to use a query like described in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query) of Firestore. It could look like this:

```
...
guard let email = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email else { return }
emailString = "\(email)"

self.db.collection("users").whereField("email", isEqualTo: emailString)
    .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
            }
        }
}
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Unfortunately, I have tried your suggested approach before, and I get the same error. I hope I can solve it sometime soon! Thanks again!!

Comment: Can you provide your code with that approach that you tried before? Do you use there a for loop too?

Comment: Your edit did it for me, thank you so much, man.
Can I ask you one thing though:
As you know, in my app, pressing a button reveals an alert: "Hello \(username)".
However, in the simulator, when I log out of one account and into another, and press the button, the alert continues to read the username of the previous user until I kill the app one or sometimes 2 times, before it resets. Do you have any thoughts on this? Or do you think I should ask a new question for this issue?

Comment: Glad it helped :) To not spam the comments section and because it is another question it's better to ask a new question I think :)

Comment: I understand, I'll clean the comment up, and thanks again!